# Why global variable inside jQuery each() function is breaking up my rollover effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, this, each

I'm trying to accomplish a rollover effect through jQuery in which when I hover over a black & white image, it gets replaced by the colored one & when I move out of the image, the original B&W image appears again. The code I'm using is :

```
var origImgSrc;
$('#gallery img').each(function() {
    origImgSrc = $(this).attr('src');
    var imgExt = /(\.\w{3,4}$)/;
    var newImg = origImgSrc.replace(imgExt, '_h$1');
    $(this).hover(function() {
      $(this).attr('src', newImg);
     }, function() {
      $(this).attr('src', origImgSrc);
     }); // end hover
}); // end each
```

I have two copies of each image(one **B&W**, one **colored**). For example, **green.jpg** (B&W), **green_h.jpg** (colored). A regular expression replaces the name of image & whole code is written directly inside `$(document).ready()` method.

The code somewhat works, when I hover over any of the image, it gets replaced by its corresponding colored one but on mouseout, **irrespective of the image**, the original image now gets replaced by the last image in the markup, the actual corresponding B&W image doesn't come back.

I came down to a working solution i.e. instead of declaring `var origImgSrc;` variable **outside** the `each` function, I should define it **inside** the `each` function. The rollover effect now works perfectly but I want to find what exactly goes wrong here & the possible reason I came across for this behaviour is **Asynchronous flow** of JS or the **Asynchronicity**. Completely read about it & understood it but still I can't relate this problem to it.

Can anybody please explain in any way what's **going wrong** here? Whether by taking the help of **JS runtime's Call Stack, WebAPIs, Callback Queue,** etc. I understand these concepts but in context of quite easy examples, just can't relate in this case.

Comment: `origImgSrc` should be local to the `each()` scope ... `var origImgSrc = $(this).attr('src');`

Comment: Otherwise the same instance of `origImgSrc` will be shared by all `img` elements, so at the end of the loop, it will have the value of the last `img`

Comment: Yes I know, I've already mentioned it in my question, why being in global scope breaks the effect?

Comment: because each iteration will override the same global reference... so when the hover is called it will have the last updated value

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with asynchrony. It's just that a global variable cannot be expected to point to different images.

Comment: Can you please explain it in a bit more detail, I'm somewhat getting you.. @ArunPJohny

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? Is it not obvious that if every click handler uses the same variable, they all do the exact same thing?

Comment: Then why the new corresponding colored images are replaced successfully??  @Juhana

Comment: Because it *doesn't* use the same variable.

Comment: But `newImg` variable depends upon `origImgSrc` then how its wotking?? @Juhana

Comment: The value of `newImg` doesn't change when `origImgSrc` changes.

Comment: Thanks for your answers @Juhana, I get it completely now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because when `hover` callback runs it use global variable `origImgSrc`.
Variable `origImgSrc` rewrites every iteration and equals last image `src` after all.
Just put `origImgSrc` into your `each`.

Comment: Ok, I get you, but when `origImgSrc` is local to `each` method, then does the callback to hover again runs `each` method?? because it remains uninitialized at the end (because of being in lical scope)??